# How can I update multiple tables while guaranteeing no duplicate ids?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm used to building websites with user accounts, so I can simply auto-increment the user id, then let them log in while I identify that user by user id internally.  What I need to do in this case is a bit different.  I need to anonymously collect a few rows of data from people, and tie those rows together so I can easily discern which data rows belong to which user.

The difficulty I'm having is in generating the id to tie the data rows together.  My first thought was to poll the database for the highest user ID in existence, and write to the database with user ID +1.  This will fail, however, if two submissions poll the database before either of them writes to it - they will each share the same user ID.

Another thought I had was to create a separate user ID table that would be set to auto-increment, and simply generate a new row, then poll that table for the id of the last row created.  That also fails for the same reason as above - if two submissions create a row before either of them polls for the latest user ID, then they'll end up sharing an ID.

Any ideas?  I get the impression I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm understanding you right; I was having a similar issue. There's a super handy php function, though. After you query the database to insert a new row and auto-incrementing their user ID, do:

```
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

That just returns the auto-increment value from the previous query on the current mysql connection. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) if you need to.

You can then use this to populate the second table's data, being sure nobody will get a duplicate ID from the first one.

Comment: Very interesting, and convenient!  This is just what I need.  Any idea what sort of SQL query the function is using to grab that data?  Or is it returned with the prior insertion query?  The documentation doesn't seem to specify.

Comment: It looks like it's just calling this MySQL function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Hold up a second...wouldn't this run into the same problem as my other two ideas?  If another user is posted between the first user's post and the first "mysql_insert_id()" is called, they'll still end up sharing an ID!  Unless the ID is returned with the original insert query, and this function just refers to it.

Comment: Nah, no worries on that. From the mysql doc I linked to: The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I didn't see your post of the MySQL function, or I would have perused it myself.

Comment: The function is always returning a value of zero.  I did some digging around, and it seems that it re-initializes the value for each new connection.  As each of my queries is passed to a handler function that builds its own connection, every query I send to the SQL server exists independently of the others, an has no "prior queries" associated.

Comment: Do you have a way of getting the user id back to the source of the queries? Once it has one, it could build that into the queries it sends. Or perhaps put it in a session variable?

Comment: @Stephens  That's what I'm trying to determine.  Any query I make after I autoincrement the ID may pull a newer auto-increment than the one I need.  Everything after that is gravy.

Comment: mysql_insert_id() has been zero for me on a couple oddball servers I've worked with, too. working around it isn't easy, but possible.

Comment: Got it!  I had to build a custom access control to let me tie the two queries together on the same connection, but it works now!

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert the user, get the auto-generated id, and then use that id as a foreign key in the couple of rows you need to associate with the parent record.  The hat rack must exist before you can hang hats on it.

Comment: Well right- the difficulty is in being certain that I am grabbing the correct auto-generated ID.

Comment: when mysql_insert_id() does work, as long as you've kept the same connection open, it is guaranteed to be the right one applicable to the connection. Just make sure you call it before you execute any other queries on the connection (after the INSERT you're concerned about).

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue, and to solve it, you would use a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). This gives you the atomic idea being being able to do more than one thing, but have it tied to either a success or fail as a package. It's an advanced db feature, and does require awareness of some more advanced programming in order to implement it in as fault-tolerant a manner as possible.

Comment: I wanted to avoid transactions if I could, since it would seem to add a lot of complexity to an otherwise incredibly simple application.